# Clojure / Logic Pro

Tags: clojure, audio-player

Is there anyway to be able to script / use the synthesizer of Logic Pro from Clojure?

I have Logic Pro installed. I have Clojure installed. I would love to be able to to have the synthesizing power of Logic Pro, but the programming power of Clojure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use clojure to generate midi or osc events and use these to control synthisizers in logic

afaik logic supports osc events native

for osc there is a clojure library available at https://github.com/overtone/osc-clj
and there are several wrappers to the java midi libraries available on the net (but I haven't 
used any of them yet)